# Why do all of my GUI components move to the top left corner of my JFrame whenever I type in a text area?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I'm new to Java and Stack Overflow and I'm making a registration form that will collect user data and store it in JLabels in a resulting window. Each window is made in a separate class. I have a submit button in the original window, whose code is shown below, that calls the resulting window putting the user data that was collect from the text fields and areas and putting them into JLabels.

My question is: How come whenever I type in one of my text areas all of my components move to the top left corner of the window?

Before it used to work fine. That is until I changed my layout from null to spring, and I stopped extending from JFrame and made a JFrame object instead. So far my other class is fine and its just this one thats giving me trouble.

This is the code for the original window where the user will input text:

```
public class RegistrationForm1{
private JFrame frame;
private JButton submit;
private JLabel fnLabel, lnLabel, dobLabel, phoneLabel, cellLabel, 
ecLabel, ecnLabel, employerLabel, workLabel, alLabel, 
rLabel, ptlLabel, pcpLabel, pcpPhoneLabel;
private JTextArea alBox, rBox; 
private JTextField fnBox, lnBox, dobBox, phoneBox, cellBox, 
ecBox, ecnBox, employerBox, workBox, ptlBox, pcpBox, 
pcpPhoneBox;

public RegistrationForm1(){

    frame = new JFrame("RegistrationForm");
    frame.setLayout(new SpringLayout());
    frame.setSize(500, 570);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public void CloseFrame(){
    frame.dispose();
}

public void form1(){

    fnLabel = new JLabel("First Name: ");
    fnLabel.setBounds(114, 0, 100, 50);
    frame.add(fnLabel);
    fnBox = new JTextField(20);
    fnBox.setBounds(185, 15, 100, 20);
    fnBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(fnBox);

    lnLabel = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
    lnLabel.setBounds(115, 30, 100, 50);
    frame.add(lnLabel);
    lnBox = new JTextField(20);
    lnBox.setBounds(185, 47, 100, 20);
    lnBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(lnBox);

    dobLabel = new JLabel("Date of Birth: ");
    dobLabel.setBounds(101, 60, 100, 50);
    frame.add(dobLabel);
    dobBox = new JTextField(10);
    dobBox.setBounds(185, 77, 100, 20);
    dobBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(dobBox);

    phoneLabel = new JLabel("Phone#: ");
    phoneLabel.setBounds(134, 90, 100, 50);
    frame.add(phoneLabel);
    phoneBox = new JTextField(10);
    phoneBox.setBounds(185, 105, 130, 20);
    phoneBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(phoneBox);

    cellLabel = new JLabel("Cell#: ");
    cellLabel.setBounds(148, 120, 100, 50);
    frame.add(cellLabel);
    cellBox = new JTextField(10);
    cellBox.setBounds(185, 135, 130, 20);
    cellBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(cellBox);

    ecLabel = new JLabel("Emergency Contact: ");
    ecLabel.setBounds(59, 150, 200, 50);
    frame.add(ecLabel);
    ecBox = new JTextField(20);
    ecBox.setBounds(185, 165, 200, 20);
    ecBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(ecBox);

    ecnLabel = new JLabel("Emergency Contact Number: ");
    ecnLabel.setBounds(5, 180, 300, 50);
    frame.add(ecnLabel);
    ecnBox = new JTextField(20);
    ecnBox.setBounds(185, 197, 150, 20);
    ecnBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(ecnBox);

    employerLabel = new JLabel("Employer: ");
    employerLabel.setBounds(121, 210, 100, 50);
    frame.add(employerLabel);
    employerBox = new JTextField(20);
    employerBox.setBounds(185, 225, 200, 20);
    employerBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(employerBox);

    workLabel = new JLabel("Work#: ");
    workLabel.setBounds(139, 240, 100, 50);
    frame.add(workLabel);
    workBox = new JTextField(10);
    workBox.setBounds(185, 255, 150, 20);
    workBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(workBox);

    alLabel = new JLabel("Allergies: ");
    alLabel.setBounds(124, 270, 100, 50);
    frame.add(alLabel);
    alBox = new JTextArea();
    alBox.setBounds(185, 285, 200, 50);
    alBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(alBox);

    rLabel = new JLabel("Reason for visit: ");
    rLabel.setBounds(81, 330, 120, 50);
    frame.add(rLabel);
    rBox = new JTextArea();
    rBox.setBounds(185, 350, 200, 50);
    rBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(rBox);

    ptlLabel = new JLabel("Pain Threshold Level: ");
    ptlLabel.setBounds(50, 394, 150, 50);
    frame.add(ptlLabel);
    ptlBox = new JTextField();
    ptlBox.setBounds(185, 410, 30, 20);
    ptlBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(ptlBox);

    pcpLabel = new JLabel("Primary Care Physician: ");
    pcpLabel.setBounds(35, 420, 150, 50);
    frame.add(pcpLabel);
    pcpBox = new JTextField(20);
    pcpBox.setBounds(185, 440, 200, 20);
    pcpBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(pcpBox);

    pcpPhoneLabel = new JLabel("PCP Phone#: ");
    pcpPhoneLabel.setBounds(103, 450, 100, 50);
    frame.add(pcpPhoneLabel);
    pcpPhoneBox = new JTextField(10);
    pcpPhoneBox.setBounds(185, 470, 150, 20);
    pcpPhoneBox.setEditable(true);
    frame.add(pcpPhoneBox);

    submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.setBounds(200, 500, 70, 40);
    frame.add(submit);
    submit.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    RegistrationForm2 apollo = new RegistrationForm2();
                    apollo.form2(fnBox, lnBox, dobBox, phoneBox, cellBox, 
                            ecBox, ecnBox, employerBox, workBox, alBox, rBox, 
                            ptlBox, pcpBox, pcpPhoneBox);
                    CloseFrame();
                }
            }
            );
}
}
```

Comment: It's because you're using layouts all wrong. Get rid of `setBounds(...)` and any idea of absolute positioning and instead use the layouts in a smart way to let them position your components and size your GUI appropriately. The tutorials will guide you in using them.

Comment: If you want to use a SpringLayout, then you need to specify constraints for the layout. I suggest you start by reading the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to better understand how they work. Then take a look at the SpringLayout examples.